# Japanese character are not showing while scraping through requests with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, encoding, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a title name from a site using requests and beautiful soup library. I don't understand why the Japanese characters are not showing properly.
My code is given below in which I'm scraping the title name of Japanese torrent.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


def main():
    current_headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, "
                                     "like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36",
                       'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,jp,en;q=0.5',
                       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,'
                                 'image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
    request = requests.session()
    request.headers.update(current_headers)

    request = request.get("https://nyaa.si/user/Mashin")
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print("Successful in getting site")
        print(request.encoding)
        soup = bs(request.content, features="html.parser")
        for table_row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
            tds = table_row.find_all('td')
            print(tds[1].find("a", class_='')['title'])
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now the output I get is this:

[image: Output]
Whereas the torrent name should be like this

> [마신] [2021.08.25] TVアニメ「ひぐらしのなく頃に 卒」EDテーマ「Missing Promise」／鈴木このみ [MP3
> 320K]

Kindly help me understand the problem and what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: What terminal do you use? Running your code my linux terminal correctly shows Japanese characters.

Comment: I am using cmd in windows 10

Comment: I just ran the command in py charm and it is showing me characters properly.

Comment: I don't have experience with Windows10, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window

Comment: I am sorry, It was just the cmd issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Windows CMD and its encoding issues. I ran the commad in pycharm terminal and it showed proper Japanese characters.
Also, when I use these data into CSV and view the file using Microsoft Excel, Japanese characters are also not visible there. I am using pycharm to see the csv file as well